What compiled programming languages can implement transparent computed duck typing?
The following is pseudo code.
Let's say I have a language which supports duck typing of this form:
my_structure = {
    value_a: integer,
    value_b: integer,
}

duck_typed_function(
    ducktyped value_a,
    ducktyped value_b)
{
    return value_a + value_b;
}

my_structure instance = { 1, 2 };
result = duck_typed_function(instance);

The important part is the ducktyped hypothetical keyword. The idea being, my duck typed function searches for members named value_a and value_b from inside my structure automatically.
Next, I want a way to define computed values and use them transparently:
my_structure = {
    value_a: integer,
    value_b: integer,
    value_c: integer => value_a + value_b, // define computed member
}

computed_duck_typed_function(
    ducktyped value_c)
{
    return value_c * 2; // expands to (value_a + value_b) * 2
}

my_structure instance = { 1, 2, }; // Nothing for value_c, it's computed.. 
// Unless the computed member has some kind of code assigned
// to it to 'decompute' a value from. As in doing the inverse math 
// to get the original 2 values, if possible.

result = computed_duck_typed_function(instance);

The transparent part is the ability to use this value_c computed member with the exact same syntax as the non computed members. The idea is all I have to change to make a field computed vs not computed is the definition of that field, and all the code that uses it stays the exact same.
What compiled programming languages can implement transparent computed duck typing?

I assume that reflection wouldn't be allowed here and that the duck-typing would have to be a native language feature?

@ipodtouch0218 If reflection would allow to achieve the features I'm seeking for, I'm open to it. Native is better but I'm open to ideas.

If memory serves (which it may not -- it's been a great many years), this is a feature of Boo. That said, Stack Overflow generally doesn't allow open-ended or language/tool-selection questions; I'm not sure this is topical.

This sounds more like splatting than duck typing.
